# I'm working with facebook chat app "fbchat" for python

Tags: python-2.7

as defined in Python package at link :https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fbchat/

I'm using the examples. In my Facebook account I have two user with same name Virender. One is my junior and another one is my boss. I wan't send message to my junior which actually got delivered to my boss.

Anyway we can pass something different which is unique for particular fb account to counteract this error.